# SwiftyJSON producing blank string values

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

When I build and run the following:

```
// Grabbing the Overlay Networks

let urlString = "https://test.sdnnw.net/networks/overlay_networks"
if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
   let URLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
   URLRequest.setValue("token", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Token")
   URLRequest.setValue("username", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Auth")
   URLRequest.HTTPMethod = "GET"
   Alamofire.request(URLRequest).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in   
     if let value = response.result.value {
       let json = JSON(value)
       print(json)
     }
   }
 }
```

I get the following results (which is correct):

```
[
  {
    "uuid" : "c8bc05c5-f047-40f8-8cf5-1a5a22b55656",
    "description" : "Auto_API_Overlay",
     "name" : "Auto_API_Overlay",
  }
]
```

When I build and run the following:

```
// Grabbing the Overlay Networks

let urlString = "https://test.sdnnw.net/networks/overlay_networks"
if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
  let URLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
  URLRequest.setValue("token", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Token")
  URLRequest.setValue("username", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Auth")
  URLRequest.HTTPMethod = "GET"
  Alamofire.request(URLRequest).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in    
    if let value = response.result.value {
      let json = JSON(value)
      print(json["name"].stringValue)
      print(json["description"].stringValue)
      print(json["uuid"].stringValue)
    }
  }
}
```

I get blank output - no `null`, `nil`, or `[:]`, just blank. Scoured `SwiftyJSON` and here and haven't found anything close to clearing up why `stringValue` is not working correctly (maybe I'm searching using incorrect keywords?). Would very much appreciate some feedback as to what I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: stringValue is an optional. Try using string and check.

Comment: `SwiftyJSON` is actually not so *swifty*. When you try to parse a value that is not there, you don't get an optional, you get an empty value. True, this will prevent the app from crashing but it makes it a bit harder to find the error.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Dershowitz123 and Sulthan!  Best Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSON, the `[]` characters are for arrays, and `{}` are for dictionaries.

Your JSON result:

> [ { "uuid" : "c8bc05c5-f047-40f8-8cf5-1a5a22b55656", "description" : "Auto_API_Overlay", "name" : "Auto_API_Overlay", } ]

is an array containing a dictionary.

Get the contents with a loop, for example.

Using SwiftyJSON, loop with a tuple (first arg of a SwiftyJSON object is the index, second arg is the content):

```
for (_, dict) in json {
    print(dict["name"].stringValue)
    print(dict["description"].stringValue)
    print(dict["uuid"].stringValue)
}
```

Be careful with [SwiftyJSON properties](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#optional-getter) ending with `Value` as they are the *non-optional* getters (if the value is nil, it will crash). The *optional* getters don't have `Value`:

```
for (_, dict) in json {
    if let name = dict["name"].string,
        desc = dict["description"].string,
        uuid = dict["uuid"].string {
            print(name)
            print(desc)
            print(uuid)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer AND explain Eric D!  It worked.  Best Regards!